How to read the font color of an excel-cell?
i have the folowing excel-sheet and try to read the font-color of the cell B3:

using the following code:
import openpyxl as ox
wb = ox.load_workbook("test.xlsx")  
ws = wb.worksheets[0]  
print(ws["B3"].font.color)

But the output is as following and the rgb-value is None
$ python test2.py
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb=None, indexed=10, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='indexed'
(xlwings) 

How can i get the rgb value of the font-color?
(also other solution with eg. xlwings or xlrd would be fine of course)

B3 is rich text, so you need to open with that mode enabled and extract the blocks. See this answer

btw, just for your information, XLRD now only supports XLS files and so cannot be used to read XLSX files.

If you do wish to use Xlwings instead you'd need to use the 'characters' attribute of the cell which accepts a start and end position in the cell value to select a substring. For example ws['B3'].characters[10:16] would be the word 'Field3' from that cell value and ws['B3'].characters[10:16].font would provide the details on that text font format, including ws['B3'].characters[10:16].font.color to return the RGB value of the font-colour.
